# Recording a call in Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

Can I record a call in Voximplant? And how can I get the transcription of the conversation? For example I want to receive a call and then mail the transcript to quality control service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call.record` for recording the calls:

```
call.record({stereo:true, lossless:true, transcribe:true, hd_audio:false});
```

And the same method but with `transcribe: true` for text transcription:

```
call.record({transcribe: true, language: ASRLanguage.ENGLISH_US});
```